# Malformed base64 from canvas in safari

Tags: image, canvas, safari

I have a project where I save a canvas drawing via `canvas.toDataURL("image/webp", 0.4)` as an image/webp base64 string in a database and redraw this image to the canvas on reload. This works perfectly in Chrome on Windows. In Safari on iPadOS 14.4.2, webp seems to be still unsupported and it saves it as image/png (which I don't mind). The issue is that sometimes (maybe after reload no. 6-12) the base64 string that is saved in the database is somehow corrupt and it won't redraw it.

Example for such a corrupt string: https://pastebin.com/QfdrDjRk

I searched for a solution for a while and found out that I can repair the string with this tool: https://base64.guru/tools/repair

This is the repaired string (which can be drawn to canvas): https://pastebin.com/ZESamNM1

After comparing both strings, I noticed that they are completely identical until position 124940 where the repaired string ends and the old string continues for another 100000 characters or so.

Any idea how to prevent safari generating a wrong base64 string in the first place, or how I can repair it myself before saving the string to the database?